# Can I rollback a review?

Tags: support, review-queues

I did a [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17661777) on Late Answers queue and I marked `No Action Needed`

The answer seems detailed and with solution but when I look again on the answer I saw that there was also a question at the end

Should I marked it as not an answer, or if so can I rollback my decision somehow because I didn't see such option.

Comment: No rollback, you need to get this right the first time.  This depression-era pointless work creation scheme is useless, downvote unhelpful posts please.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention. Your account has now been banned from reviewing. (Just kidding.) No, there's no way to reverse a review, but you can always do what you would have done if you'd reviewed correctly: raise a "not an answer" flag. Fun fact: you weren't the only reviewer fooled by this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no option to undo a review action for any of the queues.

You should have taken a closer look at the post while reviewing.That is clearly asking a different question.
It begins as:

> I am looking for a similar solution to the OP. Based on the above answers I have tried the jQuery approach.

What you can do is click on the link to the original post located at the right side of the review page and then flag as not an answer/VLQ and/or downvote.

This will push it to the Low-Quality Post Queue.(Based on the comment in the actual post it may already be in the queue)

Comment: Marked as not an answer